# Unfathomable (for me) issue when searching a string for a substring in python

Tags: python, string

I have a piece of code that iterates through a list and searches a string, the list is football players names.  It works for almost every player but has randomly will not recognise a player called ashley westwood.  I have checked the list and he is definately in there, everything is lower case and the script functions because it is recognising every other player (so far)

Basically I am asking what problems can occur when using 'in'?  The DB entries I get from this make no sense at all.

I have included the code although its a bit dirty and not really relevant.

I am a relative noob too.

CODE

```
        if 'corner' in text3[:50] or ('inswinging corner' in text3) or ('outswinging corner' in text3) :
        print text3
        print time
        for player in away_players_names:
            this_player = player[0].lower()
            upper = player[0]
            if this_player in segment:
                player_id = away_team_dict[upper]
                player_id = int(player_id[0])
                etype = 10
                team = 2
                cur.execute("""INSERT INTO football.match_events(type, player, time, game_id, team) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE game_id = game_id""", (etype, player_id, time, game_id, team))  
                db.commit()
        for player in home_players_names:
            this_player = player[0].lower()
            print this_player
            upper = player[0]
            if this_player in segment:
                player_id = home_team_dict[upper]
                player_id = int(player_id[0])
                etype = 10
                print player_id
                team = 1
                cur.execute("""INSERT INTO football.match_events(type, player, time, game_id, team) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE game_id = game_id""", (etype, player_id, time, game_id, team)) 
                db.commit()
```

here is an example of a printed statement and a failure.

```
corner taken right-footed by ashley westwood to the near post
38.22
bradley guzan
ron vlaar
ciaran clark
nathan baker
matthew lowton
charles n'zogbia
ashley westwood
fabian delph
christian benteke
jordan bowery
andreas weimann
shay given
joe bennett
yacouba sylla
simon dawkins
barry bannan
darren bent
brett holman
```

This hasn't recognised the name and I have no idea why?

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
if this_player in segment:
```

What is the value of segment?

Comment: you have only nailed it.  segment is a primitive form of text3 without whitspace removed.  I am so dumb.  I need to write cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the string 'ashley westwood' in segment has trailing white space.
'ashley westwood' != 'ashley westwood '